# CharacterController movement very buggy when updating its "center" to match the VR players head in playspace

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
public override void UpdateLocomotion()
{
        GetInput();

        characterController.center = new Vector3(player.HeadGeneric.transform.localPosition.x,0.85f, player.HeadGeneric.transform.localPosition.z);

        if ((Mathf.Abs(inputAxis.x) < 0.4 && Mathf.Abs(inputAxis.x) > -0.4) && (Mathf.Abs(inputAxis.y) < 0.4 && Mathf.Abs(inputAxis.y) > -0.4)) return;

        ApplyGravity();

        Vector3 MovementForward   = (transform.forward * -inputAxis.y) * Time.deltaTime;
        Vector3 MovementSidewards = (-transform.right * -inputAxis.x) * Time.deltaTime;           

        MovementForward.y += gravityEffect;
        characterController.Move(MovementForward + MovementSidewards);

    }

    void GetInput()
    {
        inputAxis.x = Input.GetAxis(XRAxisNames.RightThumbX);
        inputAxis.y = Input.GetAxis(XRAxisNames.RightThumbY);
    }
```

Basically, I am using Unitys generic XR Rig, and have written some locomotion logic to work with the CharacterController. Everything works fine, but when I have

`characterController.center = new Vector3(player.HeadGeneric.transform.localPosition.x,0.85f, player.HeadGeneric.transform.localPosition.z);`

The movement begins jumping all over the place, even though in the scene, the CharacterController now follows the head position perfectly.
 Without the logic to adjust the center to match head, if you walk to the corner of your playspace, then walk up steps, you are now physically offset from where the actually controller body is, causing undesirable motion.

Also another strange thing, this only breaks the locomotion logic when the other controller is on, offestting the center while the other controller is disabled works, but when I turn it back on the same strange motion begins to happen.

The only thing I've noticed is removing the logic adjusting the center programmatically solves it completely.

Comment: So apparently the code updating the center for the Character controller is causing the issues.

Comment: I need to offset the position of it so It can always accurately reflect the VR Characters position in playspace. By mapping its center to match the local position of the "Head" object makes the character controller follow the head perfectly, however it seems to cause some strange movement issues, anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I didn't realize the CharacterController handled physics collisions.

What was happening was simply, my left controller had box colliders around its world space UI. resulting in it me "jumping around".

I was essentially always standing in a collision so it was constantly resolving itself when my right controller was clipping the Character controller.